# BundlerMinifier does not wait for Web-compiler

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, minify, task-runner-explorer, web-compiler

I am building a Continuous Integration and Deployment steps on VS online team services. This is an asp.net core project which is using web-compiler to compile sass/scss files and then BundlerMinifier to bundle and minify files.

I have found this question, [BundlerMinifier and WebCompiler does not output files on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165808/bundlerminifier-and-webcompiler-does-not-output-files-on-build) on stackoverflow. This is my original problem

On the build log, I've found the following message

> 2017-08-03T15:02:26.7240383Z [33m[1m  wwwroot/css/comsite.css was
>   not found[0m[39m[49m

There is a scss file that generates comsite.css file of 1143 lines. but there are some calculation going on the files, so i guess this is taking some time. So my understanding is bundler is running before web-compiler generate the file. So, i tried to run compilerconfig.json before build and bundlerconfig.json after build. it didn't help. Now, I am trying to run both after build, please check the image below

[image: TaskRunner on vs2017]

The problem is I could not move the compilerconfig up before bundler. So, my question is there any way to run compiler before bundler from task runner?

#### Updated

As stated in the comment
bundleconfig.json

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/bootstrap337.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    }
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/metro-all.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/metro.css",
      "wwwroot/css/metro-responsive.css",
      "wwwroot/css/metro-helper.css",
      "wwwroot/css/metro-icons.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/metro-base.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/metro-base.js"
    ]
  }
]
```

compilerconfig.json

```
[
  {
    "outputFile": "wwwroot/css/site.css",
    "inputFile": "wwwroot/scss/site.scss"
  },
  {
    "outputFile": "wwwroot/scss/main.css",
    "inputFile": "wwwroot/scss/main.scss"
  },
  {
    "outputFile": "wwwroot/scss/default.css",
    "inputFile": "wwwroot/scss/default.scss"
  }
]
```

And the build log for the web project

> [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build
>   d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Manager\SY.Manager.csproj --configuration release
>   /maxcpucount:3 2017-08-03T12:36:17.3376673Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine
>   version 15.1.1012.6693 2017-08-03T12:36:17.3426644Z Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>   2017-08-03T12:36:17.3426644Z  2017-08-03T12:36:18.3840789Z
>   2017-08-03T12:36:18.3840789Z   Bundler: Begin processing
>   bundleconfig.json 2017-08-03T12:36:18.7668697Z    Minified
>   wwwroot/css/bootstrap337.min.css 2017-08-03T12:36:18.7678702Z
>   [33m[1m  wwwroot/css/site.css was not found[0m[39m[49m
>   2017-08-03T12:36:19.2716108Z      Minified wwwroot/js/site.min.js
>   2017-08-03T12:36:21.9055182Z      Minified wwwroot/css/metro-all.min.css
>   2017-08-03T12:36:21.9095163Z   Bundler: Done processing
>   bundleconfig.json 2017-08-03T12:36:25.4501457Z   BS.Data ->
>   d:\a\1\s\src\BS.Data\bin\release\netcoreapp1.1\BS.Data.dll
>   2017-08-03T12:36:27.4295141Z   BS.Domain ->
>   d:\a\1\s\src\BS.Domain\bin\release\netcoreapp1.1\BS.Domain.dll
>   22017-08-03T12:36:36.2084047Z
>   Controllers\ApiResourcesController.cs(308,42): warning CS1998: This
>   async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
>   Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls,
>   or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
>   [d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Manager\SY.Manager.csproj]
>
> 2017-08-03T12:36:36.2084047Z Controllers\RolesController.cs(184,73):
>   warning CS0618: 'ApplicationRole.RoleName' is obsolete: 'Duplicate
>   field. Please use the Name field instead.'
>   [d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Manager\SY.Manager.csproj]
>
> 2017-08-03T12:36:36.4348318Z   SY.Manager ->
>   d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Manager\bin\release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Manager.dll
>   2017-08-03T12:36:42.5313140Z   Razor view compilation for SY.Manager
>   -> bin\release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Manager.PrecompiledViews.dll 
>   2017-08-03T12:36:42.5413146Z  2017-08-03T12:36:42.5413146Z Build
>   succeeded. 2017-08-03T12:36:42.5413146Z  2017-08-03T12:36:42.5413146Z
>   Controllers\ApiResourcesController.cs(150,42): warning CS1998: This
>   async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
>   Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls,
>   or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
>   [d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Manager\SY.Manager.csproj]
>   2017-08-03T12:36:42.5423139Z     6 Warning(s)
>   2017-08-03T12:36:42.5423139Z     0 Error(s)
>   2017-08-03T12:36:42.5423139Z  2017-08-03T12:36:42.5423139Z Time
>   Elapsed 00:00:25.12

### Updated Build log

Please find the log below which was created by VSOnline Build Solution task. I have added the log for full project, but remove some details to make it as short as possible

> 2017-08-18T09:14:15.9528421Z Project "d:\a\1\s\SY.sln" (1) is building
>   "d:\a\1\s\test\SY.ManagerTests\SY.ManagerTests.csproj" (11) on node 1
>   (default targets). 2017-08-18T09:14:15.9539325Z PrepareForBuild:
>   2017-08-18T09:14:15.9539325Z   Creating directory
>   "bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\". 2017-08-18T09:14:15.9539325Z   Creating
>   directory "obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\". 2017-08-18T09:14:17.9102914Z
>   Project "d:\a\1\s\test\SY.ManagerTests\SY.ManagerTests.csproj" (11) is
>   building "d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Manager\SY.Manager.csproj" (12:2) on node 1
>   (default targets). 2017-08-18T09:14:17.9102914Z BundleMinify:
>   2017-08-18T09:14:17.9102914Z    2017-08-18T09:14:17.9102914Z
>   Bundler: Begin processing bundleconfig.json
>   2017-08-18T09:14:17.9733689Z      Minified
>   wwwroot/css/bootstrap337.min.css 2017-08-18T09:14:17.9743707Z
>   [33m[1m  wwwroot/css/site.css was not found[0m[39m[49m
>   2017-08-18T09:14:18.2918725Z      Minified wwwroot/js/site.min.js
>   2017-08-18T09:14:21.9681289Z      Minified wwwroot/css/metro-all.min.css
>   2017-08-18T09:14:21.9781425Z      Minified wwwroot/js/metro-base.min.js
>   2017-08-18T09:14:21.9781425Z   Bundler: Done processing
>   bundleconfig.json 2017-08-18T09:14:21.9831479Z PrepareForBuild:
>   2017-08-18T09:14:21.9831479Z   Creating directory
>   "bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\". 2017-08-18T09:14:21.9831479Z   Creating
>   directory "obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\". 2017-08-18T09:14:24.6830316Z
>   PreComputeCompileTypeScript: 2017-08-18T09:14:24.6830316Z   C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.2\tsc.exe  --noEmitOnError
>   --listEmittedFiles 2017-08-18T09:14:24.6840303Z CompileTypeScript: 2017-08-18T09:14:24.6840303Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript\2.2\tsc.exe  --noEmitOnError --listEmittedFiles
>   2017-08-18T09:14:24.6850285Z GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
>   2017-08-18T09:14:24.6850285Z Skipping target
>   "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are
>   up-to-date with respect to the input files.
>   2017-08-18T09:14:24.7019946Z CoreCompile: 2017-08-18T09:14:24.7089830Z
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig
>   /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1705 /nostdlib+
>   /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE;RELEASE;NETCOREAPP1_1
>   /reference:C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\automapper\6.1.1\lib\netstandard1.3\AutoMapper.dll
>   {other nuget packages}...
>   /reference:C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\wiry.base32.patched\1.0.5.1\lib\netstandard1.1\Wiry.Base32.dll
>   /debug- /debug:portable /filealign:512 /nologo /optimize+
>   /out:obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Manager.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Static
>   Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /target:exe
>   /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+
>   /analyzer:C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.dll
>   /analyzer:C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.dll
>
> Controllers\ApiController.cs {other controllers}....
>   Models\ApiViewModels\CreateApiViewModel.cs {other viewmodel}...
>
> Program.cs Startup.cs Utility\Notify.cs
>   ViewComponents\HostListViewComponent.cs
>   "d:\a_temp.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
>   obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Manager.AssemblyInfo.cs
>   2017-08-18T09:14:24.7139726Z   Using shared compilation with compiler
>   from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
>
> 2017-08-18T09:14:25.4616323Z _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
>   2017-08-18T09:14:25.4616323Z   Copying file from
>   "d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Data\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Data.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Data.dll". 2017-08-18T09:14:25.4626294Z 
>   Copying file from
>   "d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Data\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Data.pdb" to
>   "bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Data.pdb". 2017-08-18T09:14:25.4626294Z
>   GetTypeScriptCopyToOutputDirectoryItems: 2017-08-18T09:14:25.4626294Z 
>   Adding items with BuildAction=TypeScriptCompile to the same
>   collections that will be populated (with items of other BuildActions)
>   by the GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target
>   2017-08-18T09:14:25.4875852Z
>   _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways: 2017-08-18T09:14:25.4885844Z   Copying file from
>   "d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Data\appsettings.json" to
>   "bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\appsettings.json".
>   2017-08-18T09:14:25.4895830Z   Copying file from
>   "d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Manager\appsettings.json" to
>   "bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\appsettings.json".
>   2017-08-18T09:14:25.5135405Z CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
>   2017-08-18T09:14:25.5135405Z   Copying file from
>   "obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Manager.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Manager.dll".
>   2017-08-18T09:14:25.5145385Z   SY.Manager ->
>   d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Manager\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Manager.dll
>   2017-08-18T09:14:25.5145385Z   Copying file from
>   "obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Manager.pdb" to
>   "bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Manager.pdb".
>   2017-08-18T09:14:25.5454915Z MvcRazorPrecompile:
>   2017-08-18T09:14:25.5454915Z   dotnet exec --runtimeconfig
>   "d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Manager\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Manager.runtimeconfig.json"
>   --depsfile "d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Manager\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Manager.deps.json"
>   "C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation\1.1.1\build\netcoreapp1.1../../lib/netcoreapp1.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.dll"
>   @"obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation.rsp"
>   2017-08-18T09:14:32.3099160Z   Razor view compilation for SY.Manager
>   -> bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SY.Manager.PrecompiledViews.dll 2017-08-18T09:14:32.3109135Z Done Building Project
>   "d:\a\1\s\src\SY.Manager\SY.Manager.csproj" (default targets).

Here the bundler finds the css file but could not see anything from web-compiler that compile scss to css

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue with a new project? Could you share the detail build log here? Run compilerconfig.json before build and bundlerconfig.json after build work for me.

Comment: @starain-MSFT Not really, other projects do not have this issue. If i just add part of the build log will it help?

Comment: So, just this project has the issue? You can post Get source and Build log here. Also, post the code of bundleconfig.json and compilerconfig.json.

Comment: I guess, the issue is related to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5457)

Comment: Your issue related to the source files that generated through compiler that is not related to that issue. Could you post the detail build log, bundleconfig.json and compilerconfig.json here?

Comment: @starain-MSFT I have added those details on the question

Comment: Try to use Visual Studio Build task and check the result.

Comment: @starain-MSFT locally it works fine. there are no issue on local build

Comment: I mean using Visual Studio Build task instead in build definition.

Comment: @starain-MSFT, the log has been added. I guess by mentioning "Visual Studio Build task" you mean "Build solution **\*.sln"

Comment: Based on the log, there isn't warning/error and wwwroot/css/site.min.css has been minified, Does the issue have been solved?

Comment: @starain-MSFT you are right, to work around the issue one of my colleague just add the generated css file in the source control. For this readon, there are no errors in the log. I will try to reproduce the issue and will post the build task log

Comment: You can try to re-create compilerconfig file.

Comment: @starain-MSFT thanks for staying with me. I have updated the post with new build task log, please check again. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you re-create compilerconfig file through VS?

Comment: @starain-MSFT what do you mean by re-create?

Comment: Delete compilerconfig.json file, then right click a file > Web Compiler >Compile file, right-click the compilerconfig.json >Enable Compile on build, in Task Runner Explorer >compilerconfig.json> All files> Bindings> Before Build.